# Cosmic Omelet - A study on space

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

[image]

(Author Note) A while ago I made some puzzles for a now defunct puzzle hunt project, here's one of them. The answer to this ([and most other puzzles of said hunt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22A+study+on%22+is%3Aquestion)) is a single word. The puzzle itself is fully contained within the image above. Author notes don't matter.

TRANSCRIPT:

> **COSMIC OMELET**
> *Can't make an omelet without some nice scrambled moons*
> UMERRY
> SVUN
> HOMONEAR
> BOSSPROMOMEISAH
> CISGAYMENLOLDETOURPORTEAJUPIAI
> RAPMETALDISCOTUTTIDANSETHYMEANTISANSEISUEU
> AURIELLEISNOTANUMBERBANARIURIT
> TONENURTPENT
> CRUHLATOON

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As clued by the phrase

> *scrambled moons*,

each of the lines

> is an anagram of the name of a planet (including Pluto) and some of its largest moons,

with the catch that

> a letter is missing.

Here are the explanations for each line.

> Missing Letter: List of planet and moons
>  **C**: MERCURY
>  **E**: VENUS
>  **T**: EARTH, MOON
>  **D**: MARS, PHOBOS, DEIMOS
>  **E**: JUPITER, EUROPA, GANYMEDE, IO, CALLISTO
>  **N**: SATURN, TITAN, ENCELADUS, MIMAS, TETHYS, IAPETUS, DIONE
>  **O**: URANUS, TITANIA, ARIEL, UMBRIEL, OBERON
>  **I**: NEPTUNE, TRITON
>  **P**: PLUTO, CHARON

Finally, we can unscramble these to get

> **DECEPTION**.

Comment: Congrats! The anomaly will also be fixed right away !

Comment: @Auribouros Ok, I was stuck on it for a while deciding whether it was an error or a sneaky hint to the answer. I'll update the answer once I know which letter to pick :)

Comment: Updated, congrats for the solve, hope you enjoyed it!

Comment: @Auribouros Thanks, I updated the answer accordingly. Yes, I appreciated the theming and cluing!

Comment: To be needlessly pedantic, rot13(Gur bssvpvny anzr bs Rnegu'f zbba vf "Yhan".)